# How to authenticate route53 to apigateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I have deployed an Apigateway in AWS and configured a custom domain in route53. I also configured a health check endpoint so that route53 can use this endpoint to do healthy check regularly.

The heath check endpoint is a public endpoint which I don't want to open to the public. Is there a way to add an API key on the heath check endpoint and let route53 uses that key to authenticate health check request?